Locus of points from where tangents to $x^2+y^2=a^2$ will cut axes at four concyclic points
Pair of tangents to $x^2+y^2=a^2$ from  a point $P(h,k)$
are written as
$$(hx+ky-a^2)^2=(h^2+k^2-a^2)(x^2+y^2-a^2)\cdots(1)$$
If we demand $(1)$ to represent a circle by equating the co-efficients of
$x^2$ and $y^2$, we get
$[h^2-(h^2+k^2-a^2)]=[k^2-(h^2+k^2-a^2)] \implies h^2=k^2
\cdots(2)$
Hence the required locus is $$x^2=y^2\cdots (3)$$
The method above may appear to be suspiciously interesting. The question : Is the obtained locus  (3) correct. What could be other ways of obtaining it?

Pair of tangents to $x^2+y^2=a^2$ from  a point $P(h,k)$
are written as
$$(hx+ky-a^2)^2=(h^2+k^2-a^2)(x^2+y^2-a^2)\cdots(1)$$
These tangents will cut axes at $A(x_1,0),B(x_2,0), C(0,y_1), D(0,y_2)$. These points will be concyclic if
$$OA.OB=OC.OD \implies x_1x_2=y_1y_2$$
By putting $y=0$ in (1) we get a quadratic of $x$ which gives
$$x_1x_2=\frac{a^4+(h^2+k^2-a^2)a^2}{h^2-a^2}.$$
Similarly, by putting $x=0$ in (1) we get $$y_1y_2=\frac{a^4+(h^2+k^2-a^2)a^2}{k^2-a^2}.$$
Equating these two we get $h^2=k^2$, hence the required locus as
$$x^2=y^2.$$
